# bash sed a quoted string from file but only at the Nth line

Tags: bash, sed

i know those two questions have been covered many time but i can't figure how to mix the two command in one:

get string between quote

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' "$file"
```

get line 2 from file

```
sed '2q;d' "$file"
```

many thanks for help.

EDIT:

input files are as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
# "/path/to/folder/with/file.ext"
some others lines with quoted string
```

output

```
/path/to/folder/with/file.ext
```

Comment: What is input and what output you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk would be my preferred solution here.

```
awk -F'"' 'NR==2{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine 2 sed command using this sed:

```
sed '2s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p;d;q' file
/path/to/folder/with/file.ext
```

Comment: Many thanks all for very quick help. Awk seems to be the quickest way to execute this.

Comment: I would also think awk to be simplest and quickest. Only because you wanted to combine sed commands I answered it here. But yes `q` in sed does make a difference for bigger files.

Answer (score 3):

You could *combine* the two commands by saying:

```
sed -n '2s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' filename
```

- `-n` would suppress automatic printing of pattern space
- `2` before `s` causes the substitution to be performed on line 2
- `p` prints the current pattern space

For your input, it'd produce:

```
/path/to/folder/with/file.ext
```

Comment: this work thanks. I have read in a post where anubhava provide the command `sed '2q;d' "$file"` that sed is very quicker without the `-n option` (don't know if it's true and why exactly anyway)

Comment: @user3353499 Unless your input runs into gigabytes, chances are that the difference would be unnoticeable.